# JQuery + infinite scroll not working in google nexus 7

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        var yDistance = $('html, body').scrollTop();
        //var el = $(this).get(0);
        //if (el.offsetHeight + el.scrollTop >= el.scrollHeight) {
        //if ((yDistance + $(window).height()) > ($.mobile.activePage.children('.ui-content').height() - 150)) {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {

            if (!lastIndexReached) {
                pageIndex++;
                GetWallpapers(pageIndex, pageSize);
            }
        }
    });
```

In the above code, what i am doing is when the page is scrolled to the bottom of the page a new ajax request will be called and appended to the list.this works every where i mean at least in my browser and my simulator but when i run it on google nexus 7 it is not firing.i google and tried some fixes which are commented in the snippet but it did not helped.

i am using jquerymobile + phonegap.

Comment: Have you tried using setInterval with scrollcheck instead of scroll event?

Comment: i just tried that putting all the code in a function and calling that function using setIntetrval but still the function is not getting called in the google nexus 7

Comment: If you haven't, put console.log('test') in the beginning of the function to be 100% sure that the function is not being run.

If the function is being run, but something is stopping the whole function, just place the console.log snippet along to see where it's jammed.

Comment: i just found that it is working in the landscape mode but not working in portrait mode.

Comment: Check for scrollTop and height values if they're ok?

Comment: it seems that its a bug in the android 

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19625

i couldnt find anything usefull in that

Comment: Then I have no more ideas.

Try to use scrolltop property directly with Javascript? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i createtd a method and called it like this

setInterval('checkScroll()',1000);

```
function checkScroll() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() >= ($(document).height() - 100)) {

        if (lastIndexReached == false && process==false) {
            process = true;
            console.log(pageIndex);
            pageIndex++;
            GetWallpapers(pageIndex, pageSize);
        }
    }
}
```

the GetWallpapers() method was called around 10 times each time the scroll was at the bottom so i created a variable process whose value changes to false and when the GetWallpapers() method is called its value becomes true and when new html is appened to dom i set its value to false again.

this way i solved my problemm bundle of thanks to  @Ivan Ivković ,thanks for the help man.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue turned out to be related to viewport settings. I didn't really test it much, but I'm pretty sure turning off user scaling is what did the trick. Here's my full viewport tag for posterity:

`<meta name="viewport" content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0'>`

I also changed over to [Ajax Infinite Scroll](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/) plugin instead of the oldschoool Paul Irish version, but that plugin had the same problem before i changed the viewport attributes..